# Any difference between Lock behaviour in python thread and green thread?

Tags: python, python-2.7, locking, eventlet, green-threads

Is there any difference between `threading.Lock()`, `threading.Semaphore()` behaviour in usual python thread and greenthread (eventlet)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in the behavior. However, green thread isn't actually a thread since it runs all its tasks in a single OS thread, so the `threading.Lock` and `threading.Semaphore` will behave as if it's being locked and unlocked from a single thread.

This means if you try to acquire a locked Lock or an zeroed Semaphore when using green threads, then the whole program will block forever (or until the specified timeout). Also, an RLock can only be released from the same thread it's locked, since green threads actually all run on the same thread you will be able to release an RLock from a different green thread.

In short, don't use `threading` locks when using green threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So what's the Lock alternative for green threaded environment?

Comment: The alternative is to avoid the need for locking, since you have precise control over when context switches happens, eventlet programs generally wouldn't need locking to prevent programs from trampling over each other in the middle of processing. Note with eventlet you can also monkey patch the standard library, which will replace the locks in the threading module with eventlet locks. The eventlet locks implements behavior similar to the corresponding threading lock but also cause the thread to yield, possibly causing a context switch.

Comment: Ah, right! we're using monkey patch as well! So, with monkey patch it's safe to use locks, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's better practice to structure the program so you don't need to use the monkey patched lock. Monkey patching is mainly useful when you are porting existing code that previously uses native threads or if you have have third party libraries that isn't eventlet aware and is causing problems.